# How to add compiler argument "-AparcelerStacktrace" to debug Parceler Android library

Tags: android, parceler

All is in the title ;)

I cannot get rid of this error at build time...
I've checked how to add the "-AparcelerStacktrace" compiler argument for this library but didn't find it on its [Github repo](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler).
I've also checked how to simply add a "generic" compiler argument but didn't find how too...

I'm a bit stuck with this error :/

For info, I'm using Parceler 1.0.1.

**EDIT**

Finally, the error message appeared because of a duplicate of a class with a *@Parcel* annotation...
However, I let the post opened to know how to add a compiler argument in Android ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add annotation processor arguments (`-A...`) you just need to configure the compiler.

In Maven this is configured via the `maven-compiler-plugin` as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArguments>
            <AparcelerStacktrace/>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In gradle this is configured for Android as follows:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                    parcelerStacktrace: "true"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I opened the post a long ago, but I finally had to use a compiler argument & your response helped me a lot, so I mark your answer as accepted ;) Thanks a lot!